# Can subsequent nameservers defined in /etc/resolv.conf be used if the previous nameservers can not be resolved?

Tags: centos, dns, resolv.conf

I don't know much about networking...but I've been spending a lot of time reading about it.

In my `/etc/resolv.conf` I have listed 3 `nameservers`.  I understand that the second name namer is used only if the first one has a failure, or times out.

Is there a way for me to get it to use the second one when the first one cannot be resolved?

This is on my Centos workstation.  I'm not running a nameserver.

Comment: Just to clarify, you mean /etc/resolv.conf, yes?

Comment: @Nick yes - edited the question...thx

Comment: I just wanted to point out that I was able to use dnsmasq to send name-resolution queries for private network to a private nameserver (http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/323600/79893)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way for me to get it to use the second one when the first one cannot be resolved?

The DNS resolver will only move onto the other name servers if the first one returns an error (i.e `SERVFAIL`) or can't be reached. If the DNS server returns `NXDOMAIN` then the resolver considers that the proper answer and won't check the others. `NXDOMAIN` is considered a final definitive answer that the requested domain does not exist.

If you're asking this because you have a local DNS server that's authoritative for a local domain, then you should set up forwarders on that DNS server so that it can resolve all your domain names for you. You can still list the non-local DNS after that one in `resolv.conf` as a precaution against failure, but your local DNS has to be first because the other DNS servers returning `NXDOMAIN` will stop name resolution.

Comment: (Sorry for late comment) Is the initial paragraph described somewhere like a manpage?

Comment: @AhmetAlpBalkan from `man resolv.conf` : "(The  algorithm used is to try a name server, and if the query times out, try the next, until out of name servers, then repeat trying all the name servers until a maximum number of retries are made."

And of course getting an NXDOMAIN response from the server qualifies as "not timing out."