# how to get dnsmasq private nameserver to work with networkmanager?

Tags: linux, networking, linux-mint, networkmanager, dnsmasq

Just learning about networking.

I'm on Mint-18.  Use `network-manager`. `dnsmasq` is enabled.

I would like addresses that end with a particular domain-name to get resolved through a private-nameserver.

When I add a private-nameserver using the `server` option to the dnsmasq configuration file, everything fails.  I can't even resolve google.com:

```
> nslookup google.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reache
```

If I remove the `server` option and add the same private-nameserver to the top of `\etc\resolve.conf`, restart network-manager things work again and I can resolve private-hosts names.

```
> nslookup abcprivate.net
Server:     nn.nn.nn.nn
Address:    nn.nn.nn.nn#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   abcprivate.net
Address: mm.mm.mm.mm
```

So I know that the private-nameserver is correct.  So it must be the way I'm configuring dnsmasq.

Here is my config file

```
>cat /etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/dnsmasq.conf
server=/abcprivate.net/nn.nn.nn.nn
```

where abcprivate.net is the domain of the private network, and nn are digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that my settings were correct but they weren't being used.

```
>ps ax | grep dnsmasq
 1273 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground --no-hosts --bind-interfaces --pid-file=/var/run/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.pid --listen-address=127.0.1.1 --cache-size=0 --conf-file=/dev/null --proxy-dnssec --enable-dbus=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq --conf-dir=/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d
```

As can be seen it wasn't using the conf file...I did a few other tests to make sure that was the case.

---

I did end up solving the problem, but I did it by:

- Disabling Network-manager dnsmasq plugin: comment out `dns` line in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`
- Moving the `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/dnsmasq.conf` to `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`
- Adding a catch all name server to the /etc/dnsmasq.conf (see bellow for file listing)
- Adding the dnsmasq address to the top of the /etc/resolve.conf (by changing `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` file...see bellow for file listing)
- Starting dnsmasq such that it won't read the resolve.conf: `dnsmasq -d -R -q` (I wanted to log the queries on the screen so that I could see what was going on).
- One I had everything working I encapsulated the dnsmasq in a systemD unit-file

---

```
$ cat /etc/dnsmasq.conf
cache-size=1000
listen-address=127.0.1.1
server=8.8.8.8
server=/abcprivate.net/nn.nn.nn.nn
cache-size=1000

$ cat /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head    
nameserver 127.0.1.1

$ cat /etc/systemd/system/dnsmasq.service
[Unit]
Description=SystemD - Dnsmasq is a Domain Name System (DNS) forwarder
Requires=network-manager.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/dnsmasq -d -q -R
```

Comment: I followed you solution and I was trying to add dnsmasq to systemD like you have in `/etc/systemd/system/dnsmasq.service`

but it doesn't start on reboot
> sudo systemctl status dnsmasq.service

`● dnsmasq.service - SystemD - Dnsmasq is a Domain Name System (DNS) forwarder
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/dnsmasq.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/dnsmasq.service.d
           └─50-dnsmasq-$n`

Any advice ... ?

Comment: @RaduGabriel Sorry I don't know...it may not start automatically but you can always start it manually.  The important thing for me was to dnsmasq to work.

Comment: The /etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.c/dnsmasq.conf is ignored for many if not all parameters because some of them are hardcoded in NetworkManager source code. See this post: http://shiliangya.blogspot.com/2016/02/networkmanager-conflict-with-dns-cahing.html and also because one of the hardcoded settings is conf-file=/dev/null which prevents a conf-file from being read, even if the parameter for the conf-file-dir is also set.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `dnsmasq` can do what you want, but it also sounds like you've got some problems with `dnsmasq.conf`

You probably need this line uncommented in `dnsmasq.conf`:

```
resolv-file=/etc/dnsmasq.resolv
```

Then you need a file `/etc/dnsmasq.resolv` with some other nameserver in it. I've got this:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 4.3.2.1
```

Further, I think you need lines somewhat like these in `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`:

```
server=/.intranet/10.0.0.3
server=/0.0.10.in-addr.arpa/10.0.0.3
local=/.intranet/
```

The first one sets the IP address server for the ".intranet" domain. My original DSL modem used 10.0.0.0/24 addresses inside, so that's what I've got today. The 2nd line lets you look up hostnames from IP addresses. The third line tells `dnsmasq` to look up fully qualified names in ".intranet" domain in `/etc/hosts`, or from what clients register in `dnsmasq` DHCP. 10.0.0.3 is the IP address of the machine running `dnsmasq`.

To summarize: `dnsmasq.resolv` sets the IP address that `dnsmasq` will forward other names to. The `server` and `local` settings determine the IP address of a DNS server for a particular domain, and where to get addresses for names in that domain.

Comment: Thank you.  But i wasn't able to use your answer.  I could not configure dnsmasq as a plugin to network manager.